# Duplication in careers search result

Tags: bug, status-completed, jobs, search

I was just searching some job posts and I got duplicate records in the search result list.

**parameter search**
where: Germany
distance: 500 miles

The following job listing (ID = 9847) came up three times in the results.

C# Web developer
http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs/9847/c-sharp-web-developer-octavalent?campaign=List

Comment: Confirmed - looking into...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be working correctly now.